# have new outliers after capping

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, outliers

I'm trying to cap outliers in a column my pandas DataFrame.
Here's the boxplot for a column of my original data.
[boxplot for a column of my original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fc6B.png)
So, using code from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420114/11814996), I tried capping outliers.

Here's how capped column looks like, with new outliers after upper bound.
[only with outliers at upper bound capped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgdet.png)
my problem now is, i can't keep capping outliers, yes!
what do i do now.

Comment: What is this a price of, if it is something you can disclose?

Comment: price of hotels. link to data: https://www.kaggle.com/stevezhenghp/airbnb-price-prediction

Comment: There is no reason to believe those are outliers as far as I can tell.  You should be careful with capping because you would be surrendering information about the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Some distributions are inherently right-skewed, and almost all samples
from them have boxplot outliers. In some cases, repeated 'capping' can seem
to be never-ending.

In the following example, a simulated sample in R of size $n=1000$ from a standard exponential distribution (mean and rate both 1) gets capped ***three***
times, using the upper 'fence' of the boxplot outlier rule as the criterion. And there
is still more capping to be done.

```
set.seed(1234); n = 1000
x1 = rexp(n)
 cap1 = quantile(x1,.75)+1.5*IQR(x1)
x2 = x1[x1 <= cap1]
 cap2 = quantile(x2,.75)+1.5*IQR(x2)
x3 = x2[x2 <= cap2]
 cap3 = quantile(x3,.75)+1.5*IQR(x3)
x4 = x3[x3 <= cap3]
boxplot(x1, x2, x3, x4, col="skyblue2")
 abline(h = c(cap1,cap2,cap3), col=c("red","green2","blue"))
```

[image]

You have to be clear about your reason for capping. If you have a good
reason, maybe you have a good 'cap' to go with it. Then you could cap just once, based on a reasonable standard---not based on what data
you happen to get.

In my exponential example above, about 95% of the population has values
of 3 or below. Maybe just choose 3 as the cap.

*Addendum:* Almost all exponential samples of size only $n=100$ have at least one outlier and the average number of outliers among such samples is more than 4.8.

```
set.seed(2019)
nr.out = replicate(10^6, 
           length(boxplot.stats(rexp(100))$out))
mean(nr.out); mean(nr.out > 0)
[1] 4.850963
[1] 0.990244
round(table(nr.out)/10^6, 4)
nr.out
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9 
0.0098 0.0423 0.0954 0.1470 0.1744 0.1687 0.1388 0.0985 0.0619 0.0340 
    10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18 
0.0170 0.0077 0.0030 0.0011 0.0004 0.0001 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

The distribution of the number of outliers per sample of 100 is roughly Poisson with mean 4.85.